# Natural Collocations (Finance)

Tags: grammar, word-usage, finance

Could you please tell me what the native-like option for this case is:

> He diversifies his stock portfolio

OR

> He varies his stock portfolio.

I am talking about the stock market (finance).

Comment: Definitely the first option. In financial jargon you speak of a “diversified portfolio” to refer to a number  of different  assets   to control   your financial risk. https://www.dummies.com/personal-finance/investing/how-to-diversify-your-portfolio-to-reduce-your-financial-risk/

Answer (score 1):

Probably the former.

We generally say something *varies* if it changes over *time*. Diversifying a stock portfolio means investing it so that multiple securities with different risk profiles are held at the *same* time.

So

> He diversifies his stock portfolio

means the portfolio contains a diversity of risks at any single moment, but doesn't say anything about whether this diverse portfolio ever needs adjustment, whereas

> He varies his stock portfolio

means that he changes the contents of the portfolio over time.